# TextSpan's text doesn't show if it overflows

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, richtext

That's how it looks when I have a `WidgetSpan` and a `TextSpan`, and the text inside the `TextSpan` is too long:

problem

[image: problem]

A similar question has already been asked here [TextSpan's text doesn't show if it overflows and is placed after WidgetSpan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66531119/textspans-text-doesnt-show-if-it-overflows-and-is-placed-after-widgetspan), but the one answer isn't suitable for my problem.

I have two `Text.rich()` widgets (which each host one `WidgetSpan` and one `TextSpan`) inside an `Expanded` widget, both `Expanded` with `flex:1`, because I want them to be the same size and take as much space as they can. That's why a row is not an option, you can't (as far as I know) put two rows side by side, at this happens...

using rows

[image: using rows]

This is how it's supposed to look like, just with the `TextOverflow.ellipsis`, if the text is too long:

target UI

[image: target ui]

Here is my code:

```dart
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: Text.rich(
                        TextSpan(children: [
                          WidgetSpan(
                            child: Container(
                              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                              child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/building.svg", color: 
                                     htLightGrey),
                            ),
                          ),
                          TextSpan(
                            text: incident.building.name,
                            style: const TextStyle(
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                              color: htLightGrey, /*overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis*/
                            ),
                          ),
                        ]),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      flex: 1,
                      child: incident.department != null
                          ? Text.rich(
                              TextSpan(children: [
                                WidgetSpan(
                                  child: Container(
                                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 4.0),
                                    child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/department.svg", 
                                           color: htLightGrey),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                TextSpan(
                                  text: incident.department!.name,
                                  style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, 
                                         fontSize: 16.0, color: htLightGrey, overflow: 
                                         TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                ),
                              ]),
                              maxLines: 1,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            )
                          : const SizedBox.shrink(),
                    )
                  ],
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your target Ui, use the Wrap widget instead of the Row widget. Here, when the contents of the widget overflow/exceed it will break it to the next line, hence you'll achieve your target Ui.

Comment: I already tried that, and thats exactly what I DON'T want. Both the WidgetSpan and the TextSpan should stay in one line, not separated into two lines

Answer (score 0):

While we like to archive this UI, we are using Row as parent widget, which is perfect. Then we can split the row into tree part, left two part will get same and maximum available width. For this scenario, widget structure as follows.

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.green,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, //start from left
          children: [
            buildItem(
                text:
                    "incident.buildi cident.buildi cident.buildi cident.buildi cident.building.name"),
            buildItem(text: "incide ing.ssss"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            buildItem(text: "i ent.building.name"),
            buildItem(text: "incident.building.ssss"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
    IconButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      iconSize: 33,
      icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
    ),
  ],
),
```

And inside `Text.rich` add use `alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,` on `WidgetSpan` to set the middle.

```dart
maxLines: 1,
overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
textAlign: TextAlign.start,
```

And you will get

[image]

I am using extra container to point the UI, simply remove the container from the column. Also, you can use Row instead of Rich Text.

##### Test widget

```dart
class _TestGroundState extends State<TestGround> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
      children: [
        Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment:
                      CrossAxisAlignment.start, //start from left
                  children: [
                    buildItem(
                        text:
                            "incident.buildi cident.buildi cident.buildi cident.buildi cident.building.name"),
                    buildItem(text: "incide ing.ssss"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    buildItem(text: "i ent.building.name"),
                    buildItem(text: "incident.building.ssss"),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            IconButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              iconSize: 33,
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ));
  }

  Text buildItem({
    required String text,
  }) {
    return Text.rich(
      TextSpan(
        children: [
          WidgetSpan(
            alignment: PlaceholderAlignment.middle,
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(Icons.ac_unit),
            ),
          ),
          TextSpan(
            text: text,
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
              fontSize: 16.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    );
  }
}
```

More about [flutter layout](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout)

Comment: Could you share your buildItem() Methode? I tried different things, but nothing seems to work and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Try to run test widget, notice the changes.